# Looking for examples on how to implement something like this in Android

Tags: android, view, spinner

My senior project group is developing an android application and we would like to be able to implement something like the example found in this screenshot:

[image]

What we have right now is a Spinner drop down, the very first default will be "Add faculty...". Once you create that faculty, it will be selectable in the spinner, but in case a class has more than one faculty(ie: Professor, Teaching Assistant), we want to be able to add more than one spinner using the +/- buttons like you see here.

Any examples or leads in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything yet or you are starting from posting on stackoverflow? if you have tried something please show some code and ask specific question's.

Comment: i haven't tried anything, trying to find examples on this to implement on my own is merely a matter of perfecting the right search phrase. i'm not asking anyone to do this for just to maybe lead me in the right direction if they've implemented something similarly and had a link to an example i could read

Comment: here go read this http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i didn't ask for code fully formed and ready to go. a lot of android API examples and what not are merely examples, it is actually not that easy to just copy/paste considering all the resources + XMLs. not looking for code, like i said. the first attempt i would've made at implementing this is just adding a button to the layout that dynamically creates and deletes rows in a linear layout.

Comment: one thing you should understand is you'll always learn more if you try before you ask. Programming is a very unique paradigm which is not very easy to understand on your own but you understand the concepts better if you have done enough digging by hand before you go buy an Excavator. You'll earn lot of reputation on stackoverflow if you do some homework before you ask any question as your question will enlighten others too.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variable of ArrayAdapter and Arraylist of string to be global.

```
  ArrayList<String> art;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

And then in onCreate initialize the spinner as below

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
art=new ArrayList<String>();
art.add("professer");
       adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,art);//Items);
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         s1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

And then in button click , add new elements in array and notify the adapter

```
 public void btn_click(View v)
    {
        art.add("Technical Assistant");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will attempt to implement this tomorrow and report back.